# .Net SimpleMembership UserProfile Table Index Optimization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, ef-code-first, simplemembership

I am using the .Net Simple Membership and had it build the tables in my SQL DB.
I noticed that the UserProfiles table that is build by the following command

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("MyContext", "UserProfiles", "UserId", "UserName", true);
```

has an index on the UserId column only.  Shouldn't there be a constraint/index on UserName as well?

The Login command

```
WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe)
```

looks like it would only know the UserName and as such would preform a table scan to obtain the user.

Am i missing something here?

Thanks

Comment: I just noticed this too. I agree with you. I'm about to migrate about 60000 users onto SimpleMembership. I expect that without an index on username, performance will be awful. I'll let you know. +1